# configure phpstorm to use remote files only

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using virtual machine for the environment where I develop. `PhpStorm` is installed on host machine running on Windows. I can configure `PhpStorm` to work with remote files however PhpStorm always requires that local files be created which if modified then uploaded to remote server with FTP. Is there any way I can work with remote files without without having local copies of the files? Maybe with mounted folder?

Comment: Yes -- mounted folder will do (as long as your network is ultra fast, otherwise you *may* (or may not) experience some occasional temp lockups/freezes out of nowhere). But this is not recommended as IDE requires fast access to the project files. The recommended way is to have local files which then automatically uploaded to remote location.

Comment: Thanks, LazyOne! I just thought of this: I will have my local files and mount the folder with them to remote host. Do you think that's feasible? And what option should I then pick when creating project from existing files - `Web server is installed locally, source files are located under its document root`?

Comment: If you have remote files .. then how can you be choosing "web server is installed locally" option??

Comment: My suggestion --- brand new empty project; `Settings | Deployment` -- create and configure entry of correct type; "Remote Host" tab to browse and download remote files. This way you have full control over what you are doing. Wizard just simplifies few things (that you can always do manually anyway).. but if you are new to IDE (or have not used this particular one) it may be confusing.

Comment: I suggest checking these links: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials **2)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/?s=webinar+recording

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to configure the project and I'll get back with results :)

Comment: @LazyOne, I didn't manage to mount Windows drive to ubuntu, so I'm back to the FTP upload. Can you please tell me why file changes I make in editor are not uploaded automatically to remote server although in deployment settings I specified 'Always'? However, I can upload them manually. Can this be because I have two remote servers configured?

Comment: Screenshots please. But in any case: did you marked one of them as Default for this project? Automatic deployment works for default entry ONLY.

Comment: @LazyOne, now that I've selected one of them as default the files are uploaded automatically :). Can I select different default server for each project?

Comment: Got you, thanks a lot! Best, M